# How to remove windows mail signature while charm sharing in windows 8 xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I share one URL to  windows mail app using charm search from my application by default I am getting Sent from windows mail signature is coming in mail body. but if share the text to mail app the sent from windows mail signature is coming at bottom

is there any way I an position the mail signature at bottom?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot control this.  The only person that can remove the mail signature is the user.  Sorry.